# Python - Can't convert "int object to str implicitly

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program to add voting data to a file.

Code:

```
#test
import random
f = open("yob1963.txt","a") #Opens Yob1936
code1 = random.randint(111111, 999999)
code2 = random.randint(11111111, 99999999)
num = random.randint(1, 6)
if num == "1":
    party = "UKIP"
if num == "2":
    party = "Labour"
if num == "3":
    party = "Conservatives"
if num == "4":
    party = "Liberal Democrats"
if num == "5":
    party = "Monster Raving Loony Party"
if num == "6":
    party = "Anonnymous"
if input("Type NOCHANGE if you have no changes to make to your household or enter if you do:   ") == ("NOCHANGE"):
    #NOCHANGE exit ------------------------------------
    print("Thankyou for using vote information updater") 
else:
    name = input("Please enter you name")
    print("Ok " + str(name) + "Your codes are " + int(code1) + ", " + int(code2) + " and your party is " + str(party))
    f.write(name, ", ", code1, ", ", code2, ", ", party)
    f.close()
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alex/SkyDrive/School/L5/Computing/Random Vote/random_vote.py", line 24, in <module>
    print("Ok " + str(name) + "Your codes are " + int(code1) + ", " + int(code2) + " and your party is " + str(party))
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I have tried changing around str(code1) int(code1) ect but to no solution.

Please help

Comment: what do you think `f.write(name, ", ", code1, ", ", code2, ", ", party)` is going to do? You should also use `if/elifs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `format` for this

```
print("Ok {} Your codes are {}, {} and your party is {}".format(name, code1, code2, party)
```

Also note you're going to have an issue here

```
num = random.randint(1, 6)
if num == "1":
```

`num` is an `int` and you are comparing it to a `str`, you should be doing

```
if num == 1:
# and similar for the other if statements
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear, when concatenating strings with integers you can't directly stick together a string and an integer, you have to explicitly convert the integers to strings first. Try this:

```
print("Ok " + str(name) + "Your codes are " + str(code1) + ", " + str(code2) + " and your party is " + str(party))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Ok {name} Your codes are {code1}, {code2} and your party is {party}"
      .format(**vars()))
```